# Delphi, FileStream, read starting on 5th character

Tags: delphi, zlib

I have a tiff image that was compressed with zlib but they have stuck on a 4 character identifier at the beginning of the file.

I want to start reading the file at the 5 position, skipping the first 4 characters, then decompress it.

I have modified the following code but when it gets to the line to "LOutput.CopyFrom" it tells me DataError.

```
procedure TForm1.DecompressXE3 ;
var
  LInput, LOutput: TFileStream;
  LUnZip: TZDecompressionStream;
  FSize : int64 ;
begin
  { Create the Input, Output, and Decompressed streams. }
  LInput := TFileStream.Create(edtDecompressSrcFile.Text, fmOpenRead);

  FSize := LInput.Size ;

  LInput.Position := 5 ;

  LOutput := TFileStream.Create(ChangeFileExt(edtDecompressSrcFile.Text, '.tiff'), fmCreate);


  LUnZip := TZDecompressionStream.Create(LInput);


  { Decompress data. }
  LOutput.CopyFrom(LUnZip, FSize-4 );
//  LOutput.CopyFrom(LUnZip, 0 );

  { Free the streams. }
  LUnZip.Free;
  LInput.Free;
  LOutput.Free;


end;
```

Answer (score 6):

Position is zero-based, so you have to set  `LInput.Position := 4;` 
to skip 4 bytes.

Potential error reason - TZDecompressionStream may use the whole input stream, ignoring position setting, so extra start bytes break up decompressing process. In this case you would better to copy valid part of file to intermediate MemoryStream and provide it as input argument for TZDecompressionStream.Create.

And note that you are using FSize - size of compressed file - in copying from **decompressed** stream. You should use

```
LOutput.CopyFrom(LUnZip, 0);
or
LOutput.CopyFrom(LUnZip, LUnZip.Size);
```

Comment: The zero-based certainly was an issue.  I also took your suggestion to changed the other line to "LOutput.CopyFrom(LUnZip, LUnzip.Size );".  Problem solved. Thank you.